# Testing user HTTP proxy using PHP script

Tags: php, proxy

Welcome,

I'm writing application what will allow me to try detect what type of HTTP proxy user have installed.

Script calling remote server adding parameter `http://xxxx.php?my_ip=real_IP`

Here is my application:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


$real_ip=$_GET['my_ip'];


$ip1=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$ip2=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
$ip3=$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$ip4=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$ip5=$_SERVER['HTTP_VIA'];

$ip6=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ip_array[1]=$ip1;
$ip_array[2]=$ip2;
$ip_array[3]=$ip3;
$ip_array[4]=$ip4;
$ip_array[5]=$ip5;


if($ip6==$real_ip)
{
  echo "You are not using proxy.";  
}
else
{

if(in_array($real_ip, $ip_array))
{
    echo "You are using transparent proxy with one releave your ip.";
}
else
{

    if( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_VIA'])
    {
    echo "You are using anonymous proxy with one protect Your IP but inform www servers about using proxy";    
    }
    else
    {
    echo "You are using elite proxy, with one hide your IP and don't inform www servers about using proxy";    
    }


}
}




$table=<<<table

<p>Ip  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR FOR : $ip1</p>
<p>Ip  HTTP_X_FORWARDED  : $ip2</p>
<p>Ip  HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR FOR : $ip3</p>
<p>Ip  HTTP_CLIENT_IP FOR : $ip4</p>
<p>Ip  HTTP_VIA FOR : $ip5</p>
<p>Ip  remote addr  : $ip6</p>

table;
echo $table;

?>
```

I run some tests and application looks working very well.

If you have any tips please tell me.

I mean i would like know am i dont miss something important.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Another way in which some major players (Paypal, eBay, sites that have high security etc) find proxies is by looking up your IP's hostname with gethostbyaddr() which can reveal a source that is likely to be a proxy E.g. server.squid.com (Very obvious example to show you what I mean!)